# Joining huge files with python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to process and join about 200 text files (*.cov), each about 1GB in size (containing about 5 million lines), using python.
The files look like this:

001_VA.cov

`gene55970: 188/300  Percentage:62.6667  Depth:1.2
gene2664777: 0/456  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene1537538: 407/606    Percentage:67   Depth:2
gene3911524: 0/315  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene55971: 185/264  Percentage:70   Depth:1.8
gene1537539: 0/621  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene1268688: 1687/3573  Percentage:47   Depth:2
gene3911521: 0/315  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene1268689: 0/744  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene3911522: 0/165  Percentage:0    Depth:nan`

015_MA.cov

`gene55970: 0/300    Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene2664777: 0/456  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene1537538: 0/606  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene3911524: 0/315  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene55971: 113/264  Percentage:43   Depth:1
gene1537539: 0/621  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene1268688: 2298/3573  Percentage:64   Depth:2.4
gene3911521: 0/315  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene1268689: 0/744  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene3911522: 0/165  Percentage:0    Depth:nan`

079_MC.cov

`gene55970: 0/300    Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene2664777: 0/456  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene1537538: 0/606  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene3911524: 0/315  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene55971: 0/264    Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene1537539: 0/621  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene1268688: 1372/3573  Percentage:38   Depth:1.3
gene3911521: 0/315  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene1268689: 0/744  Percentage:0    Depth:nan
gene3911522: 0/165  Percentage:0    Depth:nan`

And the output should be a tab separated matrix

merged.tsv 

`gene    length  001_VA.cov  015_MA.cov  079_MC.cov
gene1268686 654 0   0   0
gene1268687 1401    0   0   0
gene1268688 3573    2   2.4 1.3
gene1268689 744 0   0   0
gene1537538 606 2   0   0
gene1537539 621 0   0   0
gene1859184 264 0   0   0
gene1859185 759 1   0   2.7
gene1859186 138 3.8 0   1`

When working with smaller subsets of these files, am able to process them with my script. However, the task becomes really impossible when I process everything together.
I need help with a script that can possibly perform this task efficiently and hopefully in a multi-thread mode.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os, glob, re, csv
enter code here
my_dict = {}
os.chdir("/path/to/files")
headers = []
x = "".join(("{}\t{}".format("gene","length")))
headers.append(x)
for file in sorted(glob.glob("*.cov")):
    header = str(file)
    headers.append(header)


f = open(file,'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('gene'):
            line = line.strip()
            line = re.split('\t|:|/',line)
            #print(line)
            gene = str(line[0])
            length = str(line[2])
            key = "".join(("{}\t{}\t".format(gene,length)))
            if line[6] == 'nan':
                value = 0
            else:
                value = line[6]        
            if my_dict.get(key,0)==0:
                my_dict[key] = [value]
            else:my_dict[key].append(str(value))

        else:
            next

with open("merged.tsv", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write('\t'.join(headers[0:])+'\n')
    for key in sorted(my_dict.keys()):
       outfile.write(str(key) + '\t'.join(str(i) for i in my_dict[key]) + '\n')
    outfile.write('\n')
outfile.close()
```

Comment: your result will be a 200GB text file? don't you think that is where you should be using a database?

Comment: How can I achieve that, because, in the end, that output file is an input for another tool!  Besides, the outfile should be probably 1/4 of the input size since most of the input information is discarded.

Comment: sill, i'd import all your files into a DB (they are way more efficient for what you want to do! and you can do that easily one file at a time) and then export the data in the format you need in a separate step.